# Jest, how to compare two strings with different format?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I use `Jest` write unit tests.

Here is the test output:

```
expect(string).toContain(value)

Expected string:
  "      input CreateBookInput {
        title: String
        author: String!
      }
      input UpdateBookInput {
        title: String
        author: String
      }
    "
To contain value:
  "
      input CreateBookInput {
        title: String
        author: String!
      }
      input UpdateBookInput {
        title: String
        author: String
      }
    "
```

This test is failed. Though these two strings' content are same, but the formatter is different.

I want this unit test pass. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it just the whitespace at the beginning and end that is different or is it different in the middle too? You could try using `.trim()` on the strings before comparing.

Comment: No, I don't want to use `RegExp` or `string` methods like `.trim()` to process my string.

Comment: If the formats are different on purpose then exact string matching might not work. You will have to find a different way to compare. You could manually go through each character, ignoring whitespace, and ensure each string has the same characters. If the formats are not different on purpose, then maybe the solution is to make whatever is creating them use the same format.

Comment: @lemieuxster Thanks for your advice. I find a way like yours.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the return value of your function like this:

```
const expectValue = `
  input CreateBookInput {
    title: String
    author: String!
  }
  input UpdateBookInput {
    title: String
    author: String
  }
`;
```

But for the unit test, we want to ignore the formatter of the string. The way is to remove all whitespaces of the string so that they can be compared with content.

`expect(actualValue.replace(/\s/g, '')).toEqual(expectValue.replace(/\s/g, ''));`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing all the white spaces from the string, another good way to fix this problem is to format the strings with the same pattern. I fixed this problem importing the `format` function from `prettier` module:

```
import {expect} from '@jest/globals'
import {format} from 'prettier'

const htmlStr = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Test</div>
  </body>
  </html>
`

const expectedHtmlStr = `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
              <title>Sample</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <div>Test</div>
            </body>
            </html>
`

const formatStmt = (str: string) => format(str, { parser: 'html' })

// The test passes
expect(formatStmt(htmlStr)).toBe(formatStmt(expectedHtmlStr))
```